# Android Accessibility: Need to press tab key twice to move to next element for the first element of the page

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility, android-include

I am facing a problem in Android 13 where there is a scenario when a page is loaded, the user needs to access the elements by the keyboard for navigation.

When the page gets loaded it focus appears on the element but the selection does not show upon the element. So, as a result user needs to press Tab key twice to get selection back on that element.

It is working fine on Android 12 or below but facing the issue in Android 13.

Below are the codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/language_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_simple"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/language_list"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/language_toolbar"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/size_2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/language_toolbar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**toolbar_simple.xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_toolbar_menu_back"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cl_toolbar_menu_back"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_back_menu"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:accessibilityHeading="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/gray1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_20"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cl_toolbar_menu_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_toolbar_menu_offline"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_50dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cl_toolbar_menu_offline"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusedByDefault="true"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/app_bar_toolbar_second_level"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_menu_offline"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_offline_indicator_badge"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_save"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_50dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="@color/gray1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_skip"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_50dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```